# Algorithmic question regarding permutations

Tags: functions, algorithms

An algorithm i'm reading has the first step saying. The algorithm is a path enumeration algorithm which puts all permutations into lexicographic order. The algorithm works as follows

Input: A natural number $n \geq 3$. A set $\{p_{1},p_{2},...,p_{n}\}$ of points in the plane.

Output: A permutation $\pi^{*}:\{1,2,...,n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,...,n\}$ with $cost(\pi^{*})=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d(p_{\pi^{*}(i)},p_{\pi^{*}(i+1)})$ minimum.

$(1)$ Set $\pi(i)=i$ and $\pi^{*}=i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$. Set $i=n-1.$

$(2)$ Let $k=\{\pi(i)+1,\pi(i)+2,...,n+1\}/\{\pi(i-1),\pi(i-2),...,\pi(1)\}$

$(3)$ If $k \leq n$ then:
set $\pi(i)=k$.

If $i=n$ and $\mathrm{cost}(\pi) \leq \mathrm{cost}(\pi^{*})$ then set $\pi=\pi^{*}$.

If $i<n$ set $\pi(i+1)=0$ and $i=i+1$.

If $k=n+1$ then set $i=i-1$.

If $i \geq 1$ go to $(2)$.

It then proceeds to say in any reasonable computer $(1)$ will take at least $2n+1$ steps as at least this many variable assignments are done. I do not see this surely $n$ variable assignments are done?

Comment: Perhaps more context is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're

- assigning to the variable $i$ the values from $1$ to $n$ -> $n$ steps
- assigning to the variable $\pi(i)$ the value $i$ for all $i$ -> $n$ steps
- assigning to the variable $i$ the value $n-1$ -> $1$ step

so $2n+1$ assignments in total

Comment: Sorry can you add more detail? Surely in your explanation you've used $n+1$ steps.

Comment: edited. You count as an assignment also the change of value of $i$

Comment: Ok this makes sense, it says 'at least' surely this is exact then? It goes on to say it takes at most $cn$ steps for some constant $c$.